# IE Webdriver pageSource is not refreshing after chnage in page due to javaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to automate a Web application using Selenium in C#,
On home page, i'm clicking on link which leads to another page.
then i switch to this new page using following code
                `string parent = webDriver.CurrentWindowHandle;
                while (webDriver.WindowHandles.Count <= 1) ; // wait for new tab
                foreach (string handle in webDriver.WindowHandles)
                {
                    if (handle != parent)
                    {
                        webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
                        break;
                    }
                }`

this new page has only two links (to select user role)
after clicking on second link, Entire page changes by a javascipt and new data is loaded on the same page
But, Even after the Page has changed, webdriver returns same pageSource (of the page that had 2 links)

title of the changed page is given correctly by the browser
I've read in the documentation that IE webdriver not always returns latest pageSource 

 consdering that, it is only the page Source which is incorrect and driver is handling the chnaged page that i'm expecting 
So i did a small test using  
  `webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath(//a);`
but it did not give the tags from changed page, instead gave tags from page which had two selection links.
why the driver is not returning the latest tags ? 
i'm stuck on this issue and i will really appreciate any help ..
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I would wait for an element indicating that the page is fully loaded before getting the page source:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

// switch to the next window
String main_handle = driver.getWindowHandle();
wait.until((WebDriver drv) -> {
    for (String handle : drv.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (handle != main_handle) {
            drv.switchTo().window(handle);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});

// wait for an element which presence indicates that the page is loaded
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("...")));

// get the page source
String page_source = driver.getPageSource();
```